# Fourier integral representation of the inverse of $\operatorname{Shi}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\sinh(t)}t dt$

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, inverse-function, riemann-sum, trigonometric-integrals

**Via Fourier Integral:**

$\def\Shi{\operatorname{Shi}}$
The [hyperbolic sine integral Shi$(x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=hyperbolic+sine+integral) is invertible via [complex fourier series](http://math24.net/complex-form-fourier-series.html) converging on $[-L,L]=[-\Shi(l),\Shi(l)]$:

$$f(x)=\Shi(x)\implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac1{2L}\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}e^\frac{\pi i nx}L\int_{-f^{-1}(L)}^{f^{-1}(L)} e^{-\frac{i\pi n\Shi(w)}L}\sinh(w)dw=\frac1{2\Shi(l)}\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}e^\frac{\pi i nx}{\Shi(l)}\int_{-l}^l e^{-\frac{i\pi n\Shi(w)}{\Shi(l)}}\sinh(w)dw$$

Plotting $f^{-1}(\Shi(x))=x$ by truncating the Fourier series [shows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%22-5%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%7Bx%2C+sum%5Be%5E%28pi+i+n+Shi%28x%29%2FShi%285%29%29+Nintegrate%5B%28e%5E%28-%28i+%CF%80+n%28Shi%28t%29%29%29%2FShi%285%29%29+sinh%28t%29%29%2F%282+Shi%285%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C-5%2C5%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%225%22) the inverse function:[image]

$\lim\limits_{L\to\infty}$ should use the [**Fourier integral theorem**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem):

$$f^{-1}(x)\mathop=^?\iint_{\Bbb R^2}e^{2\pi i(x-w)t}f^{-1}(w)dwdt=2\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{2\pi i(x-\Shi(w))t}\sinh(w)dwdt $$

Unfortunately, it is [hard to compute](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=double+integral+&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend2%22%7D+-%3E%222%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend1%22%7D+-%3E%222%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22double+integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22e%5E%282+i+%CF%80+t+%28-1+-+Shi%28w%29%29%29+sinh%28w%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable1%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart1%22%7D+-%3E%22-2%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable2%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart2%22%7D+-%3E%22-2%22) and the integrals are not interchangeable. Trying $y=\frac wl$ and assuming one may interchange the limit:

$$f(x)\mathop=^?\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\int_{-1}^1\lim_{l\to\infty}e^\frac{\pi i n(x-\Shi(ly))}{\Shi(l)}\frac{l\sinh(ly)}{2\Shi(l)} dy$$

**Via Sifting Property:**

Using the [Dirac delta $\delta(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/) [sifting property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4609778/how-applicable-is-f-1x-int-abt-deltaft-xdft-for-equation-solvin) gives:

$$f^{-1}(x)=\int_a^b\delta(\Shi(w)-x)\sinh(w)dw,a\le f^{-1}(x)\le b $$

After a [$\delta(y)$ integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+representation+delta%28s%29):

$$f^{-1}(x)\mathop=^? \frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_a^b e^{it(\Shi(w)-x)}dt\sinh(w)dw\mathop=^?\frac1{2\pi}\int_a^b\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{it(\Shi(w)-x)}\sinh(w)dwdt$$

Numerical [tests](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%282+pi%29Nintegrate%5Be%5E%28i+t+%28Shi%28w%29-1.5%29%29+sinh%28w%29%2C%7Bw%2C0%2C1.4%7D%2C%7Bt%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D) are hard to process even though the integral does converge. Strong evidence for this method working is in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453946/how-is-the-inverse-fourier-transform-derived-from-the-fourier-transform) which uses the sifting property to derive an [inverse Fourier transform](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+Fourier+transform)

If both of these methods work, what is a final double integral result?

Comment: perhaps this is related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691291/fourier-series-of-the-inverse-of-a-function

Comment: @chroma Thanks. That is how the $f^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}(\dots)$ was calculated at the top of the post.

Comment: ***Happy New Year !***

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $\color{green}{\text{Thanks. }}\color{blue}{\text{You too!}}$

Comment: ___**`And, happy (late) Christmas 8)`**___