# How applicable is $f^{-1}(x)=\int_{a}^bt\delta(f(t)-x)df(t)$ for equation solving?

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, distribution-theory, inverse-function, dirac-delta

Even though [integrating numerically gives $0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5Bdelta%28t-0.3%29+DawsonF%28t%29%2C%7Bt%2C-0.4%2C0.4%7D%5D), we use the [**Dirac delta $\delta(x)$sifting property**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiftingProperty.html) to potentially invert functions:

$$\int_{x-c}^{x+c}f(t)\delta(t-x)dt=\int_{-c}^cf(t+x)\delta(t)dt=f(x)\mathop\implies^{t\to f(t)} f^{-1}(x)= \int_{f^{-1}(x-c)}^{f^{-1}(x+c)}t\delta(f(t)-x)df(t),f^{-1}(x-c)<f^{-1}(x)<f^{-1}(x+c),c>0$$

Then rename the integral bounds:

$$f^{-1}(x)=\int_{a}^bt\delta(f(t)-x)df(t),a<f^{-1}(x)<b\tag 1$$

[**Confirmed here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%5B%282+t+DiracDelta%5B-x+%2B+Erf%5Bt%5D%5D%29%2F%28E%5Et%5E2+Sqrt%5BPi%5D%29%2C%7Bt%2Ceulergamma%2Ccatalan%7D%5D) with the [inverse error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html). However, this integral reminds one of a floor function integral:

$$xe^x=1\implies x=\frac34-\int_0^\frac34\lfloor te^t \rfloor dt=\frac 34-\int_x^\frac34 dt$$

$\lfloor te^t \rfloor:$
[image]

which is trivial. A possible transformation is using [a limit expansion of $\delta(x)$](https://books.physics.oregonstate.edu/LinAlg/deltareps.html) which numerically works:

$$f^{-1}(x)=\lim_{c\to0}\frac c\pi\int_a^b \frac{t\,d f(t)}{|f(t)-x+ic|^2}$$

Does $(1)$ provide a trivial expression of the inverse function or how applicable is it to solving equations?

Comment: Well for one thing it gives the sum of all the solutions to $f(t)=x$ in the interval. Besides that, analytically this is essentially trivial. It is a bit like those expressions for the nth prime that effectively implement an primality test and a loop inside a mathematical expression.  Numerically, you could use an approximate identity to get some estimates perhaps. The problem is that if you think about doing this with something like adaptive quadrature, it is rather similar to just bisection.

Comment: About the **Confirmed here** link you provide, Did you check [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot++InverseErf%5Bx%5D%2C+eulergamma%2C+catalan%2C)? Looks like the valid interval is quite small for the inverse error function

Comment: @Joako The “catalan/eulergamma” constants were meant to show that any numbers $a>b$ could be plugged into the bounds. Try [this example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%5B%282+t+DiracDelta%5B-x+%2B+Erf%5Bt%5D%5D%29%2F%28E%5Et%5E2+Sqrt%5BPi%5D%29%2C%7Bt%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D) with $a=-10,b=10$.